# SQL perform INSERT for every updated row in UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-trigger

I've got an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger that will almost always be executed against multiple rows at a time.  It needs to do updates, deletes, and inserts when that happens.  For the updates/deletes I'm handling the multiple rows like so:

```sql
DELETE lss
FROM dbo.Lab_SubSpace lss
JOIN Inserted i ON lss.Lab_Space_Id = i.id
WHERE i.Occupancy_Status_code = 'vacant' OR i.Status_Code IN ('retired', 'unknown');
```

Where I'm stuck now though is that I need to also do inserts into another table for each row which was updated. I'm not sure how to handle that other than just using a cursor to loop over the `Inserted` table and then perform the `INSERT INTO` operation.  So something like so:

```sql
DECLARE c CURSOR 
FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY LOCAL 
FOR SELECT i.id, i.Floor_Space_Area_Qty, sp.WWID
FROM Inserted i
JOIN dbo.Space_Planners sp ON i.Building_Location_Id = sp.LocationId
WHERE i.Status_Code NOT IN ('retired', 'unknown');

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @labSpaceId, @sqFt, @poc;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Lab_SubSpace (...)
    VALUES (@labSpaceId, @sqFt, @poc, ...);

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @labSpaceId, @sqFt, @poc;
END
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: ***YES!!!!*** A **cursor** inside a trigger is probably the most horribly slow thing you can do!! Use a **proper, set-based** approach instead....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Lab_Subspace(<field1>, <field2>, <field3>)
SELECT i.id, i.Floor_Space_Area_Qty, sp.WWID
FROM Inserted i
JOIN dbo.Space_Planners sp ON i.Building_Location_Id = sp.LocationId
WHERE i.Status_Code NOT IN ('retired', 'unknown')
```

Comment: I'm looking for the facepalm emoji :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating over the `inerted` table using a `cursor` and inserting the records one by one, simply use `insert...select`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Lab_SubSpace (...)
SELECT i.id, i.Floor_Space_Area_Qty, sp.WWID
FROM Inserted i
JOIN dbo.Space_Planners sp 
    ON i.Building_Location_Id = sp.LocationId
WHERE i.Status_Code NOT IN ('retired', 'unknown');
```